# Mac OS X: ask for configuration during pkg install

Tags: macos, installation, package, pkg-resources, pkg-file

I used [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to create a.pkg installer for a Mac OS X LaunchDaemon.

During install, I would like the user to be able to provide a few values for the configuration file. The resulting file is a simple text configuration file which will be sourced by a shell script when it is run.

Is there some tool that would make it easy to create a fill-in form with a few text fields? This would be presented to the user during install, and then save the values provided (or make them available to a postinstall shell script).

If there is no such tool, I guess I could do it with the shell and a few `read`s in a Terminal. But in that case, how to start that interactive shell script from my postinstall script?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @ParagBafna: no, I didn't. It was a small project for mainly personal use, so if I remember correctly, I just abandoned the fancy pkg installer project. But I would still like to know of a simple way to do something like that.

Comment: There is no option to pass a custom parameter to pkg installer. One solution is to use launchctl environment variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55511165/pass-variables-to-the-installer-on-osx-package-installer. Another solution is to pass value to executable after installation via command-line argument.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, you can do it with the Distribution.dist XML file. It is JavaScript, but I have not looked though the definitions, since it comes out all garbled on my current version of Safari.

The easiest would be to create a small applications dialog run from the script, which you have full control over.